# How to dual boot Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 13.04 with Windows Metro Boot Loader

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, boot, grub, bootloader

I'm having a laptop with 4 Partitions,

[1] 350 MB Windows System Reserverd
[2] 40 GB for Windows Installation
[3] 25 GB for Ubuntu Installation
[4] 400 GB for Data Storage

I have installed **Windows 8.1** on my BIOS (non UEFI) based laptop on Partition [2] and booted successfully.

Then I put the fast boot off and installed **Ubuntu 13.04** on Partition [3] using Live USB Key and on reboot GRUB Screen Appeared with the options to boot into either Ubuntu or Windows and both are working perfectly.

**Now the issue is, I do not like the GRUB Interface and want to replace it with Windows 8.1 Metro Boot Loader. Can anyone help me replacing it with the same ?**

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

You could use EasyBCD to add entries to the Windows 8 boot menu. Since you already have grub installed, you can EasyBCD to write the Windows bootloader back to the MBR of the hard drive.

[Get it from the official site](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) or download the [free community edition from softpedia](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/EasyBCD.shtml).

Comment: I've got win 8.1 and Xubuntu 14.04 and am unable to get the metro bootloader. EasyBCD and VisualBCD haven't helped.